# Fill in missing dates in Laravel Eloquent query

Tags: php, laravel

I have a query that is pulling my data from the table based on the `created_at` column.  I am trying to fill in the missing months for the year.  So for example, I have data for February, but thats it. How Do i fill in an amount of 0 for January then March-December?

My query to pull out based on the full month name is as follows

```
$servers = Stat::where('type','servers')->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->whereYear('created_at', '=', date("Y"))
            ->select(DB::raw("SUM(amount) as total"))
            ->get()
            ->groupBy(function($val) {
            return Carbon::parse($val->created_at)->format('F');
    });
```

In this case, I get my February and the total amount.  I'd like the rest of the amounts that don't exist to be 0, or fill in the correct info if it exists later in the year.

Comment: you have to create an array of months and increment that only base on what you had fetch in your servers.

Comment: 1. you can select all month in year and left join the Stat, however, this will be more complicated. 2.select these records with amount out. and use merge to all the init month with 0.

Comment: and there is an error with your code, you are using `sum()` for the whole year, so there is only one month.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `sum()` for the whole year, and using `groupBy` method on collection, so there is only one month.

You need to group by month like this:

```php
$servers = Stat::where('type','servers')
               ->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')
               ->whereYear('created_at', '=', date("Y"))
               ->groupBy(DB::raw("MONTH(created_at)"))
               ->selectRaw("SUM(amount) as total, create_at")
               ->get()
               ->groupBy(function($val) {
                   return $val->created_at->format('F');
               });
```

and you can use `CarbonPeriod` to create an initial month array, and then merge to the `servers`:

```php
$all_month = array();
$period = \Carbon\CarbonPeriod::create('2020-01-01', '1 month', '2021-12-31');
foreach ($period as $p) {
    $m = $p->format('F');
    if (isset($servers[$m])) {
       $all_month []= [$m => $servers[$m]->first()->total];
    } else {
       $all_month []= [$m => 0];
    }
}
```